# onclick event in a div background_image where the image is pad_left at a position?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I'm not really good on div any help would be great thank you.

my div code sample

```
<div class="width" style="background-image: url('someImage.jpg');padding-left:200px;background-repeat:no-repeat;height: 200px;" >
```

class width just set the div width at 1000px

my goal is to have the image only click able and then redirect the user to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an < a > tag with an image.

```
<a href="someURL.com">
   <img src="someImage.jpg" />
</a>
```